# Make a generic function in Java

Tags: java, function, generics

I have two methods to get data from the database. They differ only in the request and the return type. Is it possible to combine them somehow so that the code does not repeat itself?

```
public ObservableList<Car> getAllCars() {
    ObservableList<Car> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    Connection connection = MyConnection.connection;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM cars";
    try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            Car car = new Car(rs.getInt("ID"), rs.getInt("STYLE_ID"),
                    rs.getString("MAKE"), rs.getString("MODEL"),
                    rs.getInt("YEAR"), rs.getInt("PRICE"));
            list.add(car);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}

public ObservableList<Style> getAllStyles() {
    ObservableList<Style> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    Connection connection = MyConnection.connection;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM styles";
    try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            Style style = new Style(rs.getInt("ID"), rs.getString("NAME"));
            list.add(style);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can first write a functional interface that represents a function that converts a `ResultSet` to some type `T`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface ResultConverter<T> {
    T convert(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException;
}
```

Then you can write a common function that takes a `ResultConverter<T>`:

```
public <T> ObservableList<T> getAll(ResultConverter<T> converter, String query) {
    ObservableList<T> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    Connection connection = MyConnection.connection;
    try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            T t = converter.convert(rs);
            list.add(t);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Then you can leave the non-duplicated parts in `getAllStyles` and `getAllCars`:

```
// getAllCars:
return getAll(rs -> new Car(rs.getInt("ID"), rs.getInt("STYLE_ID"),
                rs.getString("MAKE"), rs.getString("MODEL"),
                rs.getInt("YEAR"), rs.getInt("PRICE")),
              "SELECT * FROM cars");

// getAllStyles:
return getAll(rs -> new Style(rs.getInt("ID"), rs.getString("NAME")),
              "SELECT * FROM styles");
```

Comment: Almost: you need a different SQL query for each type.

Comment: @MauricePerry Good catch! Thanks.

Comment: You could also use a `Function<ResultSet, T>`

Comment: @Sweeper It's working, thank you!

Comment: @AndyTurner I assumed that `ResultSet` is `java.sql.ResultSet`, so `getInt` and `getString` etc throws `SQLException`. If I use `Function`, you would have to catch the exception inside the lambda, which looks horrible IMO. Of course, if `ResultSet` is something else, and `getInt` doesn't throw checked exceptions, then I would have definitely used `Function<ResultSet, T>`.

Comment: @Sweeper fair enough, didn't notice the throws.

Comment: It's good practice to use `@FunctionalInteface` to mark functional interfaces.